# FB.login error when using JavaScript SDK inside a Facebook Page tab

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, oauth, facebook-page, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to use the JavaScript SDK inside a page tab app (for the purpose of sharing and what-not).

I'm calling FB.login after FB.init but I'm getting this error in the pop-up: 
**"An error occurred. Please try again later."**

[image: Facebook OAuth Error]

This happens both in development and when I deploy to Heroku (this is a Rails 3 app).

You can [see a sample/demo here](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Eds-Coffee-Deli/171801319561307?sk=app_325089027535440), but here's the relevant code:

```
<body>
    <div id='fb-root'></div>

    <div id='welcome_header'>
      <h1>Coupons</h1>
    </div>
    <h2>Sorry, no active coupons at this time.</h2>
    <h3>
      Sign up to receive future coupons from
      Ed's Coffee &amp; Deli
    </h3>
    <div id='form_section'>
      <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/fb/1/subscribers" class="new_subscriber" data-remote="true" id="new_subscriber" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="W3tWnguGrIMRJVXh23K6jTxmOH+QbeJZSD5CUnGf7bg=" /></div>
        <input id="subscriber_email" name="subscriber[email]" placeholder="enter email" size="30" type="text" />
        <input class="btn small btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="GO" />
      </form>
    </div>
    <script>
      //<![CDATA[
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : '179754758810880', // App ID
            channelUrl : '//localhost:5000/channel.html', // Channel File
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            oauth      : true  // parse XFBML
          });    
          // Login
          FB.login(
            function(response) {
              console.log(response);
            },
            { scope: 'publish_actions' }
          );
        };
        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function(d){
           var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
           if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
           ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
         }(document));
      //]]>
    </script>
  </body>
```

Any idea why this is happening? Can the JS SDK be used inside a page tab?

Answer (score 0):

Don't like to answer my own questions, but I was able to figure this out.

In the app settings, I didn't have "Website" checked under the integration options. I assumed because it was setup as a page tab, that wasn't necessary. But it is.

[image]

Comment: Sorry no one got to your question in time (I actually knew this one). Could you mark this as an accepted answer?